# Kinetics of Carbon Nanotubes Growth

Tags: kinetics, nanotechnology

I'm reading a paper where the author has come with these consecutive elementary reactions 
[image]

Where $C_2H_{4\ ads}$ is ethylene adsorved, $C_{ads}$ is carbon adsorved and $C_{CNT}$ is carbon that became nanotubes. The process he used to grow the nanotubes was CVD.

The author has derived this following equation, in which I couldn't derive myself and still doesn't make sense to me
$$\frac{d[C_{ads}]}{dt}=2k_1^+[C_2H_{4\ ads}] - (k_2^+ + k_1^-)[C_{ads}][H_2] $$

In the text he said he used these two approximations: $\frac{d[C_2H_4]}{dt}=0$ and $\frac{d[H_2]}{dt}=0$

First: I don't know why $\frac{d[C_2H_4]}{dt}=0$ is useful, as it never appears in the equation for $C_{ads}$.

Second: Why he didn't put $C_{CNT}$ there? (and even then $k_2^+$ happens to appear in the equation)

Third: Is this correct? Can someone give me some light?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry StackExchange.  Is it not possible that there are some typos?  Taking $\ce{C2H4}$ at steady state seems odd, making this $\ce{d[C2H4_{abs}]/dt=0}$ seems more likely as it is a transient species.  The last step only involves $\ce{C_{ads}}$ so it should only appear as $-k_2^+C_{ads}$ in the rate expression and not multiplied by $\ce{[H2]}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well, he says $d[C_2H_4]/dt=0$ because he is putting ethylene constantly into the system, so I guess it makes sense, and as you said, I agree with your last equation statement, I don't know why he plugged $k_2^+$ in the $d[C_{ads}]$ equation. I have the paper in hands but I think it's unethical to put it here.

Comment: No you should not post the paper, seems likely then that the last part is a typo. The hydrogen is then presumably swept away and so $\ce{d[H2]/dt =0}$ also which makes sense.